# Energy level crossing in quantum annealing

Tags: quantum-information

If two energy level crosses as the system evolves:

1. Does it mean that two energy eigenvalues share the same value at a particular instant, or is that any case that they can be the same until the finish time of quantum annealing?
2. After they touch with each other. Does the one that is lower before the "cross" become higher after the "cross", or it can be still lower after the "cross"?
3. Can energy level crossing happen multiple times during the evolution?

If the two energy level cross, in a particular instant of time only and assume that the system starts at ground state at the start of the quantum annealing.

1. Does that mean I will have 50% chance of going to the excited states, and 50% chance of remaining in the ground state?

Comment: Do you know about avoided level crossings?

Comment: i think avoided level crossings just mean no energy levels cross with each other.